# spring placeholder - replace value from a bean

Tags: java, spring

I want to choose a property file based which is decided by calling a method in another bean. Example

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:app-${app.getName('value')}.properties")
class AppConfig{}
```

class App is a bean in my spring boot program.
Is there a way to do it?
TLDR: I want to provide a value in placeholder by calling a method from other bean.

Comment: This definitely sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe what you're trying to get done with this approach.

Comment: @chrylis, I have updated the question. *I want to provide a value in placeholder by calling a method from other bean.*

Comment: But *why* do you want to do that? This seems like a really complicated way of doing something that should be done by user-supplied properties, profiles, or *maybe* auto-configuration.

Comment: This is because, I want to supply the environment type. 
Eg, at runtime, the runtime argument can be dev-us or prod-us. I want to remove -us from the value and use only dev to get the property file.

Comment: This is a library and it will be difficult to change the runtime arguments in all the parent applications

Comment: You're still not making sense from the perspective of Spring conventions. Spring libraries aren't supposed to add new property sources to the configuration environment.